# Fastify - Using a Middleware in preHandler, best practices?

Tags: fastify

I've created a Middleware that I need executing on a few routes but I'm unsure whether I've implemented my logic in the most efficient manner.

**Routes file**

```
function routes(fastify, options, done) {

    fastify.register(require('@fastify/formbody'))
    fastify.register(require('../../controllers/api'))

    // Middleware
    const validateMerchant = require('../../middleware/validateMerchant')

    fastify.get('/get-config', { preHandler: [validateMerchant(fastify)] }, (req, rep) => {
        getConfig(req.merchantId, rep)
    })

    done()
}

module.exports = routes
```

**validateMerchant.js**

```
const validateMerchant = (fastify) => async (req, rep, done) => {
    
    const merchant = require('../models/merchant')
    const srvcMerchant = new merchant(fastify)
    
    const merchantUuid = req?.body?.merchantUuid ?? req?.query?.merchantUuid
    const merchantId = await srvcMerchant.getMerchantIdByUuid(decrypt(merchantUuid))

    if (!merchantId) {
        return rep
            .code(404)
            .send({ message: 'Merchant not found' })
    }
    
    req.merchantId = merchantId

    // done()
}

module.exports = validateMerchant
```

**merchant.js**

```
class merchant {
    constructor(fastify) {
        this.fastify = fastify
    }

    getConfig = async (merchantId) => {
        const connection = await this.fastify.mysql.getConnection()
        const [rows] = await connection.query(
            `SELECT
            mc.boodil_points,
            mc.boodil_points_message,
            mc.logo,
            mc.qr_code,
            mc.pay_by_link,
            mc.bg_colour,
            mc.text_colour,
            mc.footer_bg_colour,
            mc.footer_content,
            mc.paragraph_1,
            mc.paragraph_2,
            mc.paragraph_3,
            mc.paragraph_4,
            mc.fields,
            mc.terms,
            mc.privacy
            FROM merchant_config mc
            JOIN merchants m
            ON m.id = mc.merchant_id
            WHERE m.id = :merchantId
            AND m.state = 1`, { 
                merchantId: merchantId
            },
        )
        connection.release()
        return rows[0]
    }
}

module.exports = merchant
```

My question is, I need the Fastify instance in the Middleware function to then pass onto the merchant model/class which in turn executes a SQL query. So I'm passing Fastify from the routes file, to validateMerchant and then to the merchant class file.

Is this the best/correct way to do it? I feel like I'm forever passing **fastify** in function arguments to make sure it's available.

I'm still fairly new to Fastify and can't help but think I'm missing a trick here.

**Lastly**, if I execute **done()** in validateMerchant.js, it for some reason runs the route endpoint twice. Why would that be happening?

Answer (score 0):

> Lastly, if I execute done() in validateMerchant.js, it for some reason runs the route endpoint twice. Why would that be happening?

Because you are using the `done` argument with and async function: `async (req, rep, done) => {`. Choose one:

1. async function: `async (req, rep) => {`
2. callback style: `(req, rep, done) => {`

You should see a warning in your console.

> Is this the best/correct way to do it? I feel like I'm forever passing fastify in function arguments to make sure it's available.

If you use named function, this is not necessary at all. [Docs](https://www.fastify.io/docs/latest/Reference/Hooks/#scope)

```js
const fastify = require('fastify')({ logger: true })

async function validateMerchant (req, reply) {
  console.log(this) // it is the fastify, you don't need to pass it
}

fastify.get('/', { preHandler: [validateMerchant] }, async (request, reply) => {
  return { hello: 'world' }
})
fastify.inject('/')
```

And yes, it is the right way to do it.

Comment: Hi Manuel, when trying your example above, I keep getting the error ```preHandler hook should be a function, instead got [object Promise]```

Comment: Because you are executing the function `validateMerchant()` and it returns a promise - don't execute it

Comment: I literally copied your code from above and changed prehandler to ```preHandler: [validateMerchant]```. It shouldn't be executing it as a function now should it?

Comment: updated code to show that my code is working. Please - review your code and remember that your previous API interfaces was `const validateMerchant = (fastify) => async (req, rep, done) => {` that is not the same I wrote here